# MapReduce - Iterating over keys and values in a reducer

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am having trouble understanding how to iterate over values. I have a mapper which will pass in something like:

```
(cat, *): 5
(cat, *): 5
(cat, dog): 1
(pigeon, dog): 1
(hello, world): 1
(cat, dog): 1
(pigeon, dog): 1
(hello, world): 1
```

I am trying to find the total value of any key/value pair with * in it so that I can use this for some statistical analysis. I am then trying to get the sum of the count for the other key value pairs as a variable to divide this with the '*' total value.

```
def reducer(self, pair, counts):
```

From the line of code above, how would I iterate over?

From the mapper I yielded as: `(item, neighbour), 1` or `(item, '*'), 1`.

I understand that the items are generator objects and so I have to iterate in a for loop to actually do anything.

EDIT: Data is read from a text file, it is then passed through in the mapper as:

`yield(word1, word2): 1`

Expected output:

```
(cat, dog): 0.33333333
```

Calculated as the number of cat, dog word pairs divided by the total of number of pairs (cat, *).

For a little more clarity, I am trying to achieve what the answer in [here has suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051137/mrjob-can-a-reducer-perform-2-operations)

Comment: Plz update your question with some solid data structure example. Are you working with a list, file etc?

Comment: @trixie It would help, if you give an example. For e.g. (cat, *) has 2 records and (cat, dog) has 2 records. For these records, what is the expected output?

Comment: (cat, *) has 10 records for example, I wish to record this in a variable. Then for every other wordpair I wish to take the value for example (Cat, pigeon), 3 and divide the value by 10 (from the cat variable) this way I can find the conditional probability so expected output would be something like: (Cat, pigeon) 0.033